# Finding repeated series of elements in array of elements

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array like this

```
 var randomArray = [1,2,1,1,1,1,0,2,1,2,3,10,12,54,10,12] etc..
```

I can Remove duplicate elements or find duplicate elements in this. But I want to log all repeating sequence of elements repeated in array. Here is the code I have tried, but it is running into infinite loop

```
  for (i = 0; i < randomLength; i++) {
    var cycle = [i],
    flag = 0,
    start = i;
    for (var j = i + 1; j < randomLength; j++) {
       if (randomArray[i] == randomArray[j]) {
         cycle.push(randomArray[j]);
         while (i <= j) {
            if (randomArray[i + 1] == randomArray[j + 1]) {
                cycle.push(randomArray[j + 1]);
            }
            i = i + 1;
            j = j + 1;
         }
         console.log(cycle);
       }
       i = start;
    }
   i = start;
 }
```

It should return me. And I don't want to regex to do the same

```
1,2
1,1
10,12

If array is ["a","d","z","e","g","h","a","d","z"]
```

then

```
output would be "a","d","z"
```

And it should be optimal solution. Please suggest me on this. At least corrections to my current code..

Comment: Why `10, 12` and not `0, 2`?

Comment: @Blender Because 0,2 sequence is repeating only once there..

Comment: This is an interesting challenge.

Comment: @groovy Yes it is.. I am trying to implement cycle detection algorithm for this :-)

Comment: Shouldn't return `[1,2], [2, 1], [1, 1]` and `[10, 12]` instead? That's all the subsequences that repeat given the initial sequence

Comment: @h3nr1x I have corrected my question It is repeating series of elements. Not sequence

Comment: Why `1,1,1,1`? That's not repeated.

Comment: @nnnnnn That was typo, I am sorry. But I am sure that I will get a possible solution cause you and Blender looked into the Question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Here is my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kCqaG/1/)**, much like @robert king 's (as I discovered after tackling the problem myself) except mine is complete (already is capable of not counting overlapping patterns) and optimised (as much as I can).

Also, returns a map of objects, so you can enumerate over it and only pull out patterns of size X, or ones that repeated Y times etc.

The following line (with the below function)

```js
getPatterns([1,2,1,1,1,1,0,2,1,2,3,10,12,54,10,12]).showRepeated();
```

will result in this;

```js
1 2 found 2 times
2 1 found 2 times
1 1 found 2 times
10 12   found 2 times
```

**CODE**

```js
function getPatterns(input, generateAll) {
    var patternMap = new getPatterns.presentation();

    var generated = [];
    var patternObj;
    var start;
    //for each item
    for (var index = 0; index < input.length; ++index) {
        //open a new slot for a new pattern start at this index
        generated.push('');

        start = 0;
        //unless told to generate all
        //skip patterns that cant possibly be repeated
        //(i.e. longer than half the input length)
        if (!generateAll && generated.length > input.length / 2)
            start = generated.length - Math.floor(input.length / 2);

        //test patterns we have generated for this index
        for (var index2 = start; index2 < generated.length; ++index2) {
            //generate a fresh lot of patterns for this index
            generated[index2] += ' ' + input[index];

            //unless told to generate all, dismiss patterns of length 1
            if (!generateAll && index2 == generated.length - 1)
                break;

            //try to fetch a pre-existing pattern, O(1)
            patternObj = patternMap[generated[index2]];
            //if this is a new pattern
            if (!patternObj) {
                //generate an object
                patternMap[generated[index2]] = {
                    lastSeen : index,
                    count : 1,
                    size : generated.length - index2
                };
                continue;
            }

            //unless told to generate all, skip patterns that overlap with themselves
            if (!generateAll && index - patternObj.lastSeen < patternObj.size)
                continue;

            //this pattern has repeated! update the object data
            ++patternObj.count;
            patternObj.lastSeen = index;
        }
    }

    return patternMap;
}
//just for a function prototype
getPatterns.presentation = function() {};
getPatterns.presentation.prototype = {
    showRepeated : function() {
        var patternObj;
        for (var pattern in this) {
            patternObj = this[pattern];
            if (patternObj.count > 1)
                console.log(pattern + '\tfound ' + patternObj.count + ' times');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: this is what I get for being late to the party :P

Answer (score 2):

I've used a "trie" tree datastructure (google it for more info).
The tree branches for each sequence.
It finds 1,1,1 as a solution since 1,1,1 occurs twice. (if you want to stop a number being repeated in two sequences, you need to count unique indexes against each node of the trie).

Here is the code: Runtime should be something like O(N^2) which could be improved on slightly.

```
var randomArray = [1,2,1,1,1,1,0,2,1,2,3,10,12,54,10,12]

var solve = function(a) {
    var trie = {};
    var sequence_set = {};
    for (var start = 0; start < a.length - 1; start += 1)  {
        var sub_trie = trie[a[start]] || {};
        trie[a[start]] = sub_trie;
        sequence = "" + a[start]
        for (var i = start + 1; i < a.length; i += 1) {
            sequence += "," + a[i]
            sub_trie[a[i]] = sub_trie[a[i]] || {};
            sub_trie = sub_trie[a[i]];
            var sub_trie_count = sub_trie.count || 0;
            sub_trie.count = sub_trie_count + 1;
            if (sub_trie_count >= 1) {
                sequence_set[sequence] = "found";
                console.log(sequence);
            }
        }
    }
    solution = "";
    for (sequence in sequence_set) {
        solution += sequence + ", ";
    }
    console.log(trie)
    return solution;
}
```

Output:

```
1,1 fiddle.jshell.net:37
1,1,1 fiddle.jshell.net:37
1,1 fiddle.jshell.net:37
2,1 fiddle.jshell.net:37
1,2 fiddle.jshell.net:37
10,12 fiddle.jshell.net:37
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 10: Object, 12: Object, 54: Object}
 fiddle.jshell.net:45
```

Comment: why is it counting '1,1,1' as a repeated sequence?

Comment: because 1111 contains 111 and 111.

Comment: ...it seems to me that a repeated sequence cannot overlap. for 111 to repeat, you would have to have 111111

Comment: I mentioned that already in my answer and a simple change that can filter out overlapping sequences.

Comment: oh, sorry...I only looked at the result...nice

Answer (score 1):

```
var randomArray = [1,2,1,1,1,1,0,2,1,2,3,10,12,54,10,12];

for(var i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
    var item = randomArray[i];
    var str  = "";    

    while(randomArray[i] == item) {
        str = str + " " + randomArray[i];   
        i++;
    }

    document.write(str + "<br />");
}
```

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ucgtm/

Comment: @Derek, reread it, slightly confusing way to represent the question. However, commenting out the sort provides what they are asking for.

Comment: @user2002360 : Thanks, but small doubt before looking into your solution. How can you find a repeating sequence in sorted array? Is that really possible... Because sorting will disturb array elements positions..

Comment: See the updated code. I removed the sorting, and it produces the sequence as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I just wrote in Haskell. (You can see how concise the language can be.) Below the code is an example of how it is implemented in the interpreter command line.

```
import Data.List

findSequences list length
  | length >= 2 = repeatedPattern list length ++ findSequences list (length-1)
  | otherwise = []
    where repeatedPattern [] _ = []
          repeatedPattern list size
            | take size list `isInfixOf` drop size list = 
                take size list : repeatedPattern (tail list) size
            | otherwise = repeatedPattern (tail list) size
```

Prelude> :load "findSequences.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( findSequences.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> let randomArray = [1,2,1,1,1,1,0,2,1,2,3,10,12,54,10,12]
*Main> findSequences randomArray (floor $ (/2) $ fromIntegral (length randomArray))
[[1,2],[2,1],[1,1],[10,12]]
*Main> let array = ["a","d","z","e","g","h","a","d","z"]
*Main> findSequences array (floor $ (/2) $ fromIntegral (length array))
[["a","d","z"],["a","d"],["d","z"]]

Comment: Thanks groovy.. I will try to translate it to JavScript

Comment: @Exception ... have success!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in php, it goes like this:

Create an array in php outside the `<script>`

`$array=array("1","2","2","1".....);`

`$result = array_unique($array);`

Then

`var randomArray = <?php echo json_encode($result) ?>;`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code may be running into an infinite loop because i and j are increasing at the same rate inside the "while" loop, so the "while" condition is not getting satisfied.